# Optimization of function value access in record using F#

Tags: function, optimization, f#, record

Is there any reason why F# is not clever enough to optimize the following code? `fast = 880` and `slow = 8090`.

```
type Data = { fn: int * int -> int }
let fn (x, y) = x + y
let data = { fn = fn }

let mutable a = 0
let s = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()

s.Start()
for i in 0 .. 1000000000 do
  a <- fn(i, i)
printfn "fast = %d" s.ElapsedMilliseconds

s.Restart()
for i in 0 .. 1000000000 do
  a <- data.fn(i, i)
printfn "slow = %d" s.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

Comment: I think your question isn't quite right.  The right question is why _doesn't_ the installer optimize it, not why _can't_ it optimize it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any reason why F# is not clever enough to optimize the following code?

I would be surprised if F# compiler is able to optimize this case. In the end, `fn` is a record field which is to hold data, not to execute functions.

Even on non-static members, the compiler can't inline them because these members are bounded by changing environment. By declaring a `let` binding, you have the advantage of static environment and the compiler is able to inline in some simple cases.

Indeed in this example the `fn` function is inlined (adding `inline` doesn't change running time). The slow example is the price you pay for having a more powerful construct at hand.

Whenever you have to create a record of functions, remember that interfaces and object expressions are better alternatives (less overheads, better intellisense):

```
type Data2 =
    abstract fn : int * int -> int

let data2 = 
    { new Data2 with
        member __.fn (x, y) = fn (x, y) }

s.Restart()
for i in 0 .. 1000000000 do
  a <- data2.fn(i, i)
printfn "a bit slow = %d" s.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

This is the result I got by executing in F# Interactive 64-bit:

```
fast = 614
slow = 7498
a bit slow = 2765
```

So the interface-based approach is 3x faster than record-based approach and 3x slower than the inline method.

Answer (score 4):

The fast path is inlining `fn`, but the slow path is doing a function call.

Note, you don't even need the record, it is enough to do:

```
let fn' = fn
for i in 0 .. 1000000000 do
  a <- fn'(i, i)
printfn "slow = %d" s.ElapsedMilliseconds
```

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't really answer your question of why the compiler can't optimize it.

Comment: +1 Nevertheless, it is an excellent illustration of the problem.